# NullPointerException on Context during Initializing LayoutInflater

Tags: android, layout-inflater, android-context

I'm fetching data thru an API and trying to place them in a ListView(I've wrapped them inside a bundle first), I'm using BaseAdapter. Problem is the Context/LayoutInflater that I've passed inside a fragment to the Adapter returns a NullPointer Exception

//onPostExecute in AsyncTask

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bundle bundle) {
        if(bundle != null){
            ResultFragment resultFragment = new ResultFragment();
            resultFragment.asyncExecuted(bundle);
        }
    }
```

//Method inside Fragment

```
public void asyncExecuted(Bundle bundle) {
        listResult.setAdapter(new ResultAdapter(bundle,getActivity()));
    }
```

//Adapter Class, **error is on Adapter class specifically on initializing inflater**.

```
public class ResultAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String title, isbn, author;
    String[] s_title, s_isbn, s_rating, s_image, s_author;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ResultAdapter(Bundle bundle, Context context){
        inflater  = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        try {
            title = bundle.getString("M_TITLE");
            isbn = bundle.getString("M_ISBN_13");
            author = bundle.getString("M_AUTHOR_NAME");

            int size = bundle.getInt("M_SIMILAR_SIZE");
            s_title = new String[size];
            s_isbn = new String[size];
            s_rating = new String[size];
            s_image = new String[size];
            s_author = new String[size];

            s_title = bundle.getStringArray("M_SIMILAR_TITLE");
            s_isbn = bundle.getStringArray("M_SIMILAR_ISBN_13");
            s_rating = bundle.getStringArray("M_SIMILAR_RATING");
            s_image = bundle.getStringArray("M_SIMILAR_IMAGE_URL");
            s_author = bundle.getStringArray("M_SIMILAR_AUTHOR_NAME");
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),"Nothing is Inside!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return s_title.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return s_isbn[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_result, parent, false);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtAuthor = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtAuthor);
        TextView txtRating = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtRating);

        txtTitle.setText(s_title[position]);
        txtAuthor.setText(s_author[position]);
        txtRating.setText(s_rating[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

LOGCAT Error Entry

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `Fragment`, it is not yet attached to an `Activity` until [onAttach(Activity)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)) is called - until that point, `getActivity()` will return `null`.

You should pass your `Bundle` into your `Fragment` via [setArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)) and then retrieve it via [getArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()), and execute your `asyncExecuted` method in `onAttach()` or later in the [fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check title and other variables are existing in Api

Add code by using try and catch method .

`try{

        title = bundle.getString("M_TITLE");
        isbn = bundle.getString("M_ISBN_13");
        author = bundle.getString("M_AUTHOR_NAME");
}catch(...){}`

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I believe it's the inflater that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should verify that your fragment is still attached to an activity when onPostExecute is called by checking getActivity() for null.  If it is null, the fragment has become detached.  In this case you usually want to quit.

2) If it is a valid instance of getActivity, try this:

```
View row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_result, parent, false);
```